# How can i change the gui refresh rate in SUMO Without changing the simulation step frequency?

Tags: sumo

I am running long simulations using project_flow and SUMO. but i don't need the GUI to refresh every step of the simulation. is there any way to 
de-couple the simulation step and the gui refresh rate?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how this works in the context of flow but in general you can simply use the `sumo` executable instead of `sumo-gui` to have the same simulation without a GUI. Modifying the refresh rate is not possible, as far as I know, but minimizing the window should at least avoid all draw requests from the system.